# Multiple SQLite libraries on a single process

Tags: c++, sqlite

OS: arm-based Linux.

Programming language: C, C++

Compiler: arm gcc

We build a shared library (let's call it libFoo.so) which depends on a certain SQLite version. The SQLite library is compiled statically and linked against libFoo.so. They are all compiled with a hidden visibility (-fvisibility=hidden) and libFoo.so only exports its API symbols, so the SQLite symbols are not visible using "nm -D libFoo.so". This is to avoid symbol collisions.
This shared library only performs read-operation to a set of specific database files. These databases are expected to be opened through libFoo.so only.

Our partner builds an application using libFoo.so and links against Qt Service framework from the platform. The Qt service framework depends on the SQLite shared library from the platform which has a different version than mine. This would mean that this process loads two copies of SQLite libraries, but the one coming from libFoo.so is hidden.

Questions:

1. How likely will I end-up in the database corruption issue mentioned in [How to corrupt - Multiple copies of SQLite linked into the same application](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#posix_close_bug)? I am curious about the case(s) where it could go wrong.
2. SQLite keeps a global list of open SQLite database files. Is there any chance that the SQLite shared library accesses the global list of open database files from the SQLite static library?

In the SQLite page above, there was a solution mentioned to link against one copy of SQLite library only which means to change the build procedure of the platform which is not accessible by me.

I googled it and found an interesting discussion:

- In [The multiple SQLite problem](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7756332), there is a comment stating that it might be possible to use a SQLite as a static library and hide SQLite symbols as I did.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem when I compile my code into apple ios. Another sdk lib using another version of sqlite3.

I just rename the string sqlite3 to another random string(for example hrbw) in my sqlite3 source code and my caller of sqlite3 source code.

Then the problem will be fixed.